# What is the correct callback to get mute events from the Chromecast Receiver?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm running into an issue where, when two devices are connected to the same cast session and when `BaseCastManager.setDeviceMute()` is called from device 1, device 2 does not receive a `MediaCallback.onRouteVolumeChanged()`

What's the proper way to do this? Is there perhaps a different callback?

Here's what eventually gets called.

```
/**
 * Mutes or un-mutes the device volume.
 *
 * @throws CastException
 * @throws NoConnectionException
 * @throws TransientNetworkDisconnectionException
 */
public final void setDeviceMute(boolean mute) throws CastException,
        TransientNetworkDisconnectionException, NoConnectionException {
    checkConnectivity();
    try {
        Cast.CastApi.setMute(mApiClient, mute);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CastException("setDeviceMute", e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        throw new NoConnectionException("setDeviceMute()", e);
    }
}
```

Here's my listener:

```
private class MediaCallBack extends android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter router,
                                         RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteVolumeChanged(router, route);
            onVolumeChanged(route.getVolume());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please remove your other post, seems to be identical to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Cast Companion Library, you can use the callback `VideoCastConsumer#onVolumeChanged(double value, boolean isMute)` by extending `VideoCastConsumerImpl`, overriding that method and registering it with the `VideoCastManager`(and unregister it when not needed anymore):

```
VideoCastConsumer myConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
   void onVolumeChanged(double value, boolean isMute) {
       // do as you wish here
   }
}

VideoCastManager.getInstance().addVideoCastConsumer(myConsumer);
```

Comment: this is what I'm currently doing but onVolumeChanged does not get triggered when we mute the receiver.

Comment: From what you have posted, you are not doing that; you are listening on MediaRouter.Callback and not Cast.Listener (or using CCL, which amounts to the same thing). One more thng: if you are using CCL, don't try to register to Cast events directly, use CCL's callbacks and APIs

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen to the callback [`onVolumeChanged`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.Listener.html#onVolumeChanged()) of [`Cast.Listener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.Listener):

> public void onVolumeChanged ()
>
> Called when the device's volume or mute state has changed.